# How to draw Penrose diagram for a particle of mass $m$ in between two Schwarzchild black holes?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime

I am reading Hobson's GR book. I am curious about Penrose diagrams so I asked.

Answer (score 1):

You can't draw a Penrose diagram for a spacetime that lacks the necessary symmetry and isn't conformally flat. Normally our first step is that we take a slice or projection to reduce the number of dimensions to 2. If the spacetime lacks symmetry, then this step leaves you with something that doesn't give you complete information about the whole spacetime. The next step is to do a conformal transformation in order to compactify the space. In 2 dimensions, all spacetimes are conformally flat.

For a general spacetime, you can't do the reduction to 2 dimensions without losing the picture of the whole spacetime, and if you can't reduce it to 2 dimensions, then you can't compactify it, because it isn't conformally flat.

Comment: I am getting your points it means we can draw a penrose diagrams for 4D Charged or spinning BHs ?

Comment: Because weyl tesnor is useful for external forces which determines spacetime conformal flat or not. Am I right?